# Frobenius norm minimization with two constraints: rank and semi-orthogonality

Tags: matrices, optimization

I am studying some optimization problems for a university course and I am a little stuck in one of them. Given $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$ and $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, I have an optimization problem with a semi-orthogonality constraint:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
        \min_{_{Q}} \left \| X - X QQ^{T} \right \|_{F}^{2} + \lambda \: \left \| QQ^{T} \right \|_{F}^{2} \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \: Q^{T}Q=I_{r}, \: \:  rank(Q)=r.
  \end{aligned}
\label{eq:2}
\end{equation}

I was able to find a solution by applying SVD to $X = U \Sigma Q^{T}$ just by chance. However, I don't know if it is the only solution and if there is a clear approach to solve this kind of problems.